# Symfony2 how to remove @asset/notblank constraint when heriting from entity

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine

i have the following problem :
I extend an entity tableA in a tableB entity and i want to override the @assert/notblank annotation on a field.

```
Class tableA{
...
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="please.enter.a.value")
 */
protected $myfield;
}
```

The extended class :

```
Class tableB extends tableA{
...
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4, nullable=true)
 */
protected $myfield;
}
```

The not blank constraints of TableA is still active when i make a form using tableB.

Any idea ?

I have tried with @ORM\AttributeOverride annotation but it dont works...

Comment: Can't you use [Validation Groups](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/validation.html#validation-groups) in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems indeed Symfony Validation component fails to understand what's going on.
A way around isto put the Validation constraint on the getter:

```
Class tableA{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4)
 */
protected $myfield;
}

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="please.enter.a.value")
 */
public function getMyfield()
{
    // ...
}
```

And in the extended class:

```
Class tableAB extends tableA{
public function getMyfield()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks your response it solves a part of the problem. But the second part of the problem is that i can't modify sources of tableA entity because it's in a vendor bundle...

Comment: Maybe you can still add the getter constraint? The documentation is not clear on that point, it may override anything else.